# OS X 10.6: How do I temporarily change $PATH for ZSH?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, path, zsh

I'd like to create a script that sets the $PATH to a set of directories chosen by me (thus ignoring the predefined paths, such as /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin and so on...) followed by launching ZSH.

This does the trick for BASH:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/Users/Thoht/Sites/djangostack/apps/django/bin"
# exec /bin/bash --noprofile --norc
```

I get a new BASH session with the path being only what is defined above that I cancel with Ctrl-D when done. I'd like to recreate this script for ZSH but have had no success. I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/Users/Thoht/Sites/djangostack/apps/django/bin"
# exec /bin/zsh -f
```

However the predefined paths such as /usr/bin and all that jazz remains which makes the script useless.

Preferably I'd like to have my .zshrc loaded and merely the path temporarily changed.

EDIT
I forgot to add one thing - /etc/zshenv that is read first of all (or so I believe) contains this script:

```
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

EDIT 2
The first edit is irrelevant as I don't want to use the -f option. A more precise question is:

"How do I add paths to precede the .zshrc paths to $PATH in a shell script followed by launching ZSH normally (as in with it reading .zshrc)?"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, zsh always reads the global `zshenv` file, no matter how hard you tell it not to (i.e. even when you call `zsh -f +d`).

You can make a copy of the zsh executable, replacing the string `/etc/zshenv` by `/NO!/zshenv`.

Instead of telling zsh not to load user configuration files, you can specify your own, and undo the damage done by `/etc/zshenv` in `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`.

```
export ZDOTDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
cat <<'EOF' >"$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv"
PATH="/Users/Thoht/Sites/djangostack/apps/django/bin"
EOF
zsh
rm "$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv"
rmdir "$ZDOTDIR"
```

Comment: I dabbled around for a while and realized that the script for BASH doesn't replace but simply append the directory to the front of $PATH (which is preferable) and this is what I would like to do but with ZSH. I just don't understand why the 'export PATH="/junk/and/stuff"' isn't added to the front of the path if I launch ZSH without the -f option.

Comment: @Thoht: `PATH=/junk/and/stuff` sets the path, forgetting what's there. `PATH=/junk/and/stuff:$PATH` prepends your stuff to the path. If you're seeing stuff in `$PATH` that doesn't come from you, it's because you have a `.bashrc` that's doing the same kind of things as that `zshenv` (perhaps not exactly the same thing, so that it doesn't bother you in your particular application).

Comment: I attempted this, '.zshrc' had 'export PATH="$PATH:/normal/paths/here"' and the script had 'export PATH="/junk/and/stuff:$PATH"' yet when I launched ZSH the path was set to '/normal/paths/here:/normal/paths/here' and the script had, to my knowledge, no effect.

Comment: @Thoht: That would depend on the contents of the system files (`/etc/zsh*`). I don't know what OSX puts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Whoah, I solved it. I have little to no experience in shell scripting and ZSH, hence the confusing question. Allow me to rephrase it:

**"How should I write a script that adds a bunch of directories to the front of $PATH and then runs ZSH?"**

The solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOMETHING_PATH="/junk/and/stuff:"
exec /bin/zsh
```

The .zshrc

```
...
export PATH="$SOMETHING_PATH/bin:/usr/local/bin:/the/rest/of/your/paths"
...
```